# how to read next line in csv file in Pig

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I would like to write a pig script to calculate distance between two points.
data input is

```
x,y
0.0,0.0
18.6,-11.1
36.1,-21.9
53.7,-32.6
70.1,-42.8
86.5,-52.6
101.7,-62.3
```

Distance Formula: `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`

but I can't read next line in Pig to calculate distance!

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can somehow generate a common identifier for point pairs, you can group by that and then calculate the distance.

```
ID, x, y
A, 0.0, 0.0
A, 18.6, -11.1
B, 36.1, -21.9
B, 53.7, -32.6
...
```

Group by would return something like `A, {(0.0, 0.0), (18.6, -11.1)}`. Now you can write a UDF to call on the tuple consisting of the two points which calculates the distance.

Comment: how about distance between each group? in your example, how can I calculates distance between A and B?

Comment: For that case you need to duplicate points. The thing is that map reduce is processing key value pairs and in the case of pig a single line (entry in relation) is one such pair so is processed independently from all others. So if you do not group it into one line (key value pair) it can't be processed together.